# Nexus repository configuration with dockerization

Tags: docker, configuration, nexus

Is it possible to configure Nexus repository manager (3.9.0) in a way which is suitable for a Docker based containerized environment?

We need a customized docker image which contains basic configurations for the nexus repository manager, like project specific repositories, LDAP based authentication for users. We found that most of the nexus configurations live in the database (OrientDB) used by nexus. We also found that there is a REST interface offered by nexus to handle configurations by 3rd parties, but we found no configuration exporter/importer capabilites besides backup (directory servers ha LDIF, application servers ha command line scripts, etc.).

Right now we export the configuration as backup files, and during the customized docker image build we copy those backup file back to the file system in the container:

```
FROM sonatype/nexus3:latest

[...]

# Copy backup files
COPY backup/* ${NEXUS_DATA}/backup/
```

When the conatiner starts up it will pick up the backup files and the nexus will be configured the way we need. However though, it would be much better if there was a way which would allow us the handle these configurations via a set of config files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that data is stored under */nexus-data*, so you can create an initial docker container with a docker volume or a host directory that would keep all that data. After you preconfigured that instance you can distribute your customized docker image with that docker volume containing nexus data. Or if you used a host directory you can simply copy over all that data is similar fashion as you do now, but use */nexus-data* directory instead.

You can find more information at [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/) under *Persistent Data*.

Comment: Is it working well for you? If I use host folder and then copy it to the image, the DB can't restore.

Comment: Yes, using docker volume mounted at /nexus-data works well for me. I have already went through multiple Docker and NXRM upgrades since using this setup.

Comment: If I try too move this nexus-data folder or copy it to the image, it can no longer restore. It only works if I mount the same folder. After many tries I used the backup variant (as in the question). It is also much, much smaller (400kb vs 200mb).

Comment: The size difference might be coming from dead blobs stored in your database - you can use _Admin - Compact blob store_ task to remove them. I'm not sure what do you mean by restoring - the _/nexus-data_ directory is the actual working folder with data used by NXRM. There is no restore process when re-using _/nexus-data_, but some NXRM releases do schema upgrades, so make sure you use same or newer version when migrating data.

Comment: No, what I did is start nexus->put configs->stop nexus->[move nexus-data folder->]start nexus. If I move the folder, it stops working. If I copy the folder to an image layer, it also stops working. But if I don't move the folder, it works. And size of the blob store is 0.